# Swapping integral and limit - example

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

My textbook analysis wants to show with an example that demanding **uniform continuity** to swap limits and integrals is nog always needed. (as introduction/motivation to *Lebesgue integration*)

In the example they show that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}e^{nx}} = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}e^{nx}} \quad\quad (n \in \mathbb{N})$$

I agree that the RHS equals 0 (the limit heads of to $0$ as $n \to \infty$). But why would the LHS equal zero? The book states:

> "... It also appears that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n =0$, meaning that it is allowed to swap integral en limit. However there is no uniform convergence ... "

I've checked the LHS with Wolfram Alpha, is there a way to calculate the integral of the LHS manually though (without swapping limit and integral)?

Comment: Are you asking how to evaluate $\Large{\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} e^{n x}}}$?

Comment: Indeed, that would be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $e^{nx} \ge 1 + nx$. Then for any $a > 0$ you have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x e^{nx}} \, dx \le \int_0^a \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx + \frac{1}{n} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x}} \, dx.$$ The first integral equals $2 \sqrt a$ and the second integral equals $\displaystyle \frac 2n \left[ \frac {1}{\sqrt a} - 1 \right]$. Thus
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x e^{nx}} \, dx \le 2 \sqrt a + \dfrac{2}{n\sqrt{a}}.$$ In particular, with $a = \dfrac 1n$ you have $$0 \le \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x e^{nx}} \, dx \le \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: Okay, that's a pretty cool method :).
But why is $e^{nx} \geq 1+nx$?

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of $e^{nx}$...

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit I found the following, would this be valid?

Looking at $\int_0^1 x^{\frac{-1}{2}} e^{-nx}dx$ and substituting $nx = t$ would give:
$$= \int^n_0 t^{\frac{-1}{2}}\sqrt{n} e^{-t} \frac{dt}{n}$$

With the consequence:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^n t^{\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-t}dt = 0\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0.$$

Comment: Yup, looks good to me!